# Why did Vue deprecate the "is" attribute on HTML elements?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs3

According to [Vue's eslint rules](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-deprecated-html-element-is.html), the `is` attribute on HTML elements is deprecated (since 3). One has to use it on components instead:

> ```html
> <template>
>  <!-- ✓ GOOD -->
>  <div />
>  <component is="foo">
>
>  <!-- ✗ BAD -->
>  <div is="foo" />
>  <div :is="foo" />
> </template>
> ```

I haven't found any reference in [the MDN docs, for instance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/is), of it being deprecated.

Does this refer to a Vue-specific feature that has been deprecated? How am I supposed to use the `is` attribute within Vue?

Comment: Did you check the [migration guide](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/custom-elements-interop.html#customized-built-in-elements) link in the eslint rule page?

Comment: Nope, that answers it, thank you. Deprecating it because it "now works as expected" is pretty misleading and means we will have to disable the rule. Would you like to post an answer?

Comment: No worries, you can self answer it. What they mean is they broke the expected behavior with special treatment of that property and now it works "as expected" as if in vanilla javascript/html.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone starting with Vue 3 or higher, the rule is misleading: the deprecation refers to the Vue attribute `is` and not to the HTML attribute `is`. So if you're using it as in the HTML standard, you can (and probably should) suppress the warning, as `is` works on HTML *as you would expect*.

As described in the [migration guide](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/custom-elements-interop.html#customized-built-in-elements), the `is` attribute used to customize built-in elements was faked by Vue. When the standard finally came in, this led to unexpected behaviour.

In Vue 3.x, they changed this so that plain elements would work as expected. However, it means the behaviour of `is` is different depending on what kind of element you're using:

- `<component is="xyz" />` - Vue renders the `xyz` component
- `<MyComponent is="xyz" />` - the `MyComponent` has the attribute `is`
- `<button is="xyz" />` - as in normal HTML

(thanks to [@Mat J](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77259013/why-did-vue-deprecate-the-is-attribute-on-html-elements/77267882#comment136202530_77259013) for the pointer)